# IIS Error : Remote connections are not supported

Tags: iis, windows-10, remote-administration

I have switched recently to windows 10 and have no clue if this is linked but my IIS doesn't seem to work as it used to. I previously had a remote connection to one of my website but every time I click its name in IIS it returns me an error: "Remote connections are not supported".

A quick check tells me that IIS Manager for Remote Administration is installed in its version 1.2. I have no idea what is happening and it is really frustrating because I cannot add any new website either.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I had a similar problem.  I solved it by downloading and running "IIS Manager for Remote Administration 1.2" and doing a "Repair" operation.  This did three things: 1) reduced the startup time for the IIS Manager dramatically, 2) added a "Start Page" root node in my IIS Manager Connections pane (I know this used to be there but I had not noticed it was missing after my Windows 10 update), and 3) fixed my remote connection node.

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm. I used to install ISS manager with the web platform so I could not repair it. The good installers are available here : http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-manager

Comment: I'd already had this set up on Windows 10 and it was working. Recently, after all the Spectre and Meltdown updates that were released (I don't always use it so I'm not sure when) it stopped working. This fixed it.

Comment: @IRONicMAN: Windows 10 is not one of the supported operating systems on that linked page, but it does indeed seem like a way to fix this issue on Windows 10. Also, the "Start page" root node was missing after my user's Windows 10 feature update.

Comment: Upvoted but repair didn't work for me, I had to uninstall then reinstall

Comment: Upvoted @IanNewson same solution. I had to uninstall then reinstall.